# Ubuntu don't see my Vega 8 graph card

Tags: nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen, helpfile

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 version and I have a ryzen5 3500u + vega 8 hardware, but I had freezes in the videos, then I found out that my video card was not visible, but it was visible in windows and I opened a 4k video and I saw that it is working, so it is working, how can I active it :(

Comment: Is it shown in `lspci | grep VGA`? After running `sudo apt update && sudo apt install vdpau`, can you run `vdpauinfo` and edit the output in to your question within three backticks (`) or tildes (~) as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: `sudo apt install vdpauinfo`, that should say

Comment: yes ı write grep VGA and thats not see ı try other code now...

Comment: Can you edit that information in to the original question, instead of using a pastebin? It’ll help people finding this page read through a lot quicker.

Comment: Okay, the GL video decoding driver is being used. Can you also run `sudo apt install mesa-utils` and run `glxinfo` and post the output here?

Comment: Gallium driver, not GL, sorry. Also, the output of `vainfo` would be useful too, because the two APIs are both used for video decoding and presenting.

Comment: soorry but ı can'T do wirte output code you can see my comment

Answer (score 0):

okey (ı don't know this feature :D)

vpaudinfo code:

```
display: :0   screen: 0
API version: 1
Information string: G3DVL VDPAU Driver Shared Library version 1.0

Video surface:

name   width height types
-------------------------------------------
420    16384 16384  NV12 YV12 
422    16384 16384  UYVY YUYV 
444    16384 16384  Y8U8V8A8 V8U8Y8A8 

Decoder capabilities:

name                        level macbs width height
----------------------------------------------------
MPEG1                          --- not supported ---
MPEG2_SIMPLE                    3 65536  4096  4096
MPEG2_MAIN                      3 65536  4096  4096
H264_BASELINE                  52 65536  4096  4096
H264_MAIN                      52 65536  4096  4096
H264_HIGH                      52 65536  4096  4096
VC1_SIMPLE                      1 65536  4096  4096
VC1_MAIN                        2 65536  4096  4096
VC1_ADVANCED                    4 65536  4096  4096
MPEG4_PART2_SP                  3 65536  4096  4096
MPEG4_PART2_ASP                 5 65536  4096  4096
DIVX4_QMOBILE                  --- not supported ---
DIVX4_MOBILE                   --- not supported ---
DIVX4_HOME_THEATER             --- not supported ---
DIVX4_HD_1080P                 --- not supported ---
DIVX5_QMOBILE                  --- not supported ---
DIVX5_MOBILE                   --- not supported ---
DIVX5_HOME_THEATER             --- not supported ---
DIVX5_HD_1080P                 --- not supported ---
H264_CONSTRAINED_BASELINE       0 65536  4096  4096
H264_EXTENDED                  --- not supported ---
H264_PROGRESSIVE_HIGH          --- not supported ---
H264_CONSTRAINED_HIGH          --- not supported ---
H264_HIGH_444_PREDICTIVE       --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN                      186 65536  4096  4096
HEVC_MAIN_10                   186 65536  4096  4096
HEVC_MAIN_STILL                --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_12                   --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_444                  --- not supported ---

Output surface:

name              width height nat types
----------------------------------------------------
B8G8R8A8         16384 16384    y  NV12 YV12 UYVY YUYV Y8U8V8A8 V8U8Y8A8 A8I8 I8A8 
R8G8B8A8         16384 16384    y  NV12 YV12 UYVY YUYV Y8U8V8A8 V8U8Y8A8 A8I8 I8A8 
R10G10B10A2      16384 16384    y  NV12 YV12 UYVY YUYV Y8U8V8A8 V8U8Y8A8 A8I8 I8A8 
B10G10R10A2      16384 16384    y  NV12 YV12 UYVY YUYV Y8U8V8A8 V8U8Y8A8 A8I8 I8A8 

Bitmap surface:

name              width height
------------------------------
B8G8R8A8         16384 16384
R8G8B8A8         16384 16384
R10G10B10A2      16384 16384
B10G10R10A2      16384 16384
A8               16384 16384

Video mixer:

feature name                    sup
------------------------------------
DEINTERLACE_TEMPORAL             y
DEINTERLACE_TEMPORAL_SPATIAL     -
INVERSE_TELECINE                 -
NOISE_REDUCTION                  y
SHARPNESS                        y
LUMA_KEY                         y
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L1        y
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L2        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L3        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L4        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L5        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L6        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L7        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L8        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L9        -

parameter name                  sup      min      max
-----------------------------------------------------
VIDEO_SURFACE_WIDTH              y        48     4096
VIDEO_SURFACE_HEIGHT             y        48     4096
CHROMA_TYPE                      y  
LAYERS                           y         0        4

attribute name                  sup      min      max
-----------------------------------------------------
BACKGROUND_COLOR                 y  
CSC_MATRIX                       y  
NOISE_REDUCTION_LEVEL            y      0.00     1.00
SHARPNESS_LEVEL                  y     -1.00     1.00
LUMA_KEY_MIN_LUMA                y  
LUMA_KEY_MAX_LUMA                y  
`

ı write glxinfo and there is so much code ı write start of code if u want ı     will send all code                                                           

    name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
```

and ı don't understand ast you say can you explain it ? ı am new in forum ı don't know xd thank you so much again but ı write vainfo

libva info:

```
VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.7 (libva 2.6.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Mesa Gallium driver 20.2.6 for AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.38.0, 5.8.0-63-generic, LLVM 11.0.0)
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

Comment: The output shows that libva is correctly detecting and loading the correct video acceleration driver for your hardware, and that the hardware is working, and even supports the VP9 codec required by YouTube. What web browser are you using, Firefox?

Comment: ı use chrome will ı going firefox? and one problem in system information write AMD raven don't write Vega 8 you say its Vega 8, system information is don't correct?

Comment: It might be worth trying. Firefox which ships with Ubuntu comes with all the correct video acceleration settings. It might resolve the issue.

Comment: ıok thank you ı will try and ı add something my comment you can look again  am tryin firefox now

Comment: thats fine thank you firefox more good

Comment: It's possible you are trying to play DRM-protected media content, which is not supported with video acceleration on Chrome on Linux, but is on Firefox.

Comment: ı have one little question how can ı see graphics card usage and yeah ı thinkı  play drm know more good

Comment: actually i'm sorry i thought the problem would be solved when i used firefox i was outside and i was writing from the phone i didn't want to keep you busy the answer but it started to get worse in firefox even at 480p resolution the same video is wasting 40% cpu in windows, the video freezes in firefox if you reply I would appreciate it again thank you